# Graphql query argument array of string

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I need to pass an array of strings to my query so I can iterate over it but I cant figure out how to do it.

Something like this:

```
@Query(() => Boolean)
async fetchUrl(
    @Arg('urls') urls: string[]
): Promise<Boolean> {
 // do something

 return true
}
```

```
Error: You need to provide explicit type for FetchResolver#fetchUrl parameter #0 !
```

I don't really know how to provide a proper type for an array of strings

Comment: Maybe the output type is missing instead? The input type seems to be typed.

Comment: @Herku Added the output type. Don't think that was the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@vjeko
To provide a proper type for an array of strings, you should use the second param of `@Arg` decorator and use the bracket `[]` notation:

```
@Arg('urls', type => [String]) urls: string[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by passing a stringified object instead of an array of strings, but would still be good to know how to type an array of strings in type graphql.

Answer (score -2):

@Michał Lytek's answer was almost working for me, but for anyone else struggling with it, I had to change it to this to get it working:

```
@Arg('urls', type => [String]) urls: [String]
```

Comment: It's a wrong syntax. This way you declare a TS tuple type - one-element only array of strings.